# Is the semantics of a first order logic system defined as part of the first order logic system?

Tags: computer-science, first-order-logic, formal-systems

Does a first order logic system consist **only** of

- a first order language
- a first order deductive system?

Is a first order logic system **nothing more than** a formal system?

Is the semantics of a first order logic system  defined as **part of** the first order logic system? In other words, is a first order logic system defined to also consist of its semantics? (By semantics, for example, the logical consequential relation between formulas)

Thanks.

Comment: A first order logic system *is* a formal system.

Comment: Is the semantics of a first order logic system  defined as **part of** the first order logic system? In other words, is a first order logic system defined to also consist of its semantics? (By semantics, for example, the logical consequential relation between formulas)

Comment: Yes and no. I believe it's part of a [Metalanguage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalanguage). Which resides on the border of math and philosophy.

Comment: I hope for a definite answer

Comment: It's a tough question for a concrete answer. If by semantics you mean the set of symbols used, then yes. All formal languages are defined over an "alphabet" which contains all the symbols that could be used in the system.

Comment: alphabet is part of syntax

Comment: Perhaps seeing [what is in a formal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Generic_description_of_a_propositional_calculus), namely $A, \Omega, Z, I$. Semantics may be a subset of one of those.

Comment: Part of the problem here is that this isn't exactly a precise term - "formal system" and its variants are thrown around in a bunch of different ways. I would say, though, that almost always the semantics is included. In fact, much (most?) of the time in mathematical logic the semantics comes **first** - e.g. Ebbinghaus/Flum/Thomas treat the notion of "(regular) logic" purely semantically, as essentially just a collection of classes of structures satisfying certain combinatorial properties (see the final section of the book, on Lindstrom's Theorem).

Comment: Some logics treat the semantics as external from the formal system, while others do not. See the distinction between Tarskian and Herbrand Semantics made here: http://intrologic.stanford.edu/extras/manifesto.html

Comment: We have a *language*: syntax rules to build "correct" expressions. We have a *proof system* (aka: calculus) made of axiom (maybe none) and rules (at least one) to derive correct expressions form existing ones. And we have the *semantics*, the way to give meaning to correct expressions, in such a way that only correct expressions have meaning. All this corresponds to our naive view of *language*: natural language is made of syntax+semantics.